# What would happen if I were to divide by 0 when interrupts are disabled?

Tags: exception, assembly, x86, operating-system, interrupt

When **IF** flag is cleared, (interrupt table is not ready), all maskable interrupts are disabled.

Questions are:

1. What happens if I trigger an  **exception**? (eg: `div` by zero)
2. What happens if a non-maskable interrupt arrives, (interrupt table is not ready)? What will the cpu do ?

Comment: FYI, instructions like `int 10h` also count as exceptions, because they're synchronous (need to be handled at a certain point in the code, not when you re-enable interrupts some time later).  They're not affected by IF=0 either.

Answer (score 8):

Setting `IF` to `0` (with `cli`, `popf`, `iret`, etc.) only inhibits external interrupts.

To quote [the documentation](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cli) (*Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures
Software Developer’s Manual Volume 2A*, Chapter 3.2, for the `cli` instruction):

> Clearing the IF flag causes the processor to ignore maskable **external** interrupts. The IF flag and the CLI and STI instruction have no effect on the generation of **exceptions** and NMI interrupts.

If your interrupt table (IDT or IVT) is insufficiently configured, you're likely to get a double fault that cascades into a triple fault on an instruction that raises a `#DE` divide exception (interrupt 0).

NMIs don't normally happen without some prior set up to enable something that will raise one.  (e.g. enabling a CPU performance counter event.)